# StructFindValue not working as expected

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a struct like this:

```
SESSION.Auth.Access["1"]["2"]["Write"]
```

If I `cfdump` the struct `#SESSION.Auth.Access#` I can see the struct in full and it 100% has the data in nested arrays.

However if I use this statement:

```
#StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.Access["1"], '2', 'ALL')#
```

I am getting an empty array. If I use:

```
#ArrayLen(StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.Access["1"], '2', 'ALL'))#
```

Then it returns a zero for the array length.

Am I doing something obviously wrong or is there a possible string/numeric issue going on?

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong or not but it sure looks complicated.  Maybe you can find a way to simplify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your struct could also be written like this?

```
SESSION.Auth.Access = {
   '1' = {
       '2' = {
          'Write' = 'foobar'
       }
    }
}
```

'2' is a key, not a value, so you'd need to use StructFindKey instead of StructFindValue.

Indeed this returns for me an empty array:

```
<cfdump var="#StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.Access['1'], '2', 'ALL')#">
```

But this returns me the 'Write' struct

```
<cfdump var="#StructFindKey(SESSION.Auth.Access['1'], '2', 'ALL')#">
```

Comment: @volume one you say in your question that it "100% has the data in nested arrays".  What duncan is correctly pointing out that you are not using arrays, but you are using structs.  It seems like what you want to do is determine if the "2" key exists in the `Access["1"]` struct so you could also just use `StructKeyExists` like so: `structKeyExists(session.auth.access['1'], '2')`

Comment: Thanks Sean, I used StructKeyExists instead. No idea why I went down the route of StructFindValue!